# building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64 compilation error on OpenMPI

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, openmpi

I am trying to install and run OpenMPI on VSCode using this tutorial https://medium.com/@li.nguyen_15905/setting-up-vscode-for-mpi-programming-b6665da6b4ad

> When I "Run build task" to compile the Hello.c file I receive this error:

```
(`Executing task: C/C++: mpicc build active file <

Starting build...
/Users/mohamad/opt/usr/local/bin/mpicc -g /Users/mohamad/opt/usr/local/bin/helloworld/.vscode/hello.c -o /Users/mohamad/opt/usr/local/bin/helloworld/.vscode/hello
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/mohamad/opt/usr/local/lib/libmpi.dylib, **building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64**
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_MPI_Comm_rank", referenced from:
      _main in hello-c829ad.o
  "_MPI_Comm_size", referenced from:
      _main in hello-c829ad.o
  "_MPI_Finalize", referenced from:
      _main in hello-c829ad.o
  "_MPI_Get_processor_name", referenced from:
      _main in hello-c829ad.o
  "_MPI_Init", referenced from:
      _main in hello-c829ad.o
  "_ompi_mpi_comm_world", referenced from:
      _main in hello-c829ad.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).`)
```

Running the command mpirun -np 2 hello gives:

```
mpirun was unable to find the specified executable file, and therefore
did not launch the job.  This error was first reported for process
rank 0; it may have occurred for other processes as well.

NOTE: A common cause for this error is misspelling a mpirun command
      line parameter option (remember that mpirun interprets the first
      unrecognized command line token as the executable).

Node:       Mohamads-MBP
Executable: hello
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 total processes failed to start
```

Any suggestions that could resolve this issue?

Note: All configuration settings used are included in the link.

Comment: you have wrong libraries compiled for another processor. You need to find the x86 ones.